# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Multiple membership provider and multiple login pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

It's simple configure multiple providers on Web.Config and call ValidateUser for each provider respectively.. 
But how do I use custom Authorize attribute for each provider? In my case, I wanna to use 2 distinct login pages, two distinct login controllers, and two distinct role provider.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

How does it sound to you to have 2 different custom authorize attributes.
And end result is going to be a different view being represent if user is found unauthenticated.
Or
An IPrincipal or IIdentity will be initialized. You can use the HttpContent.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and .IsInRole()

```
if (CurrentProvider.ValidateUser())
{
     CustomIdentity1 idn = new CustomIdentity1(userName);
     filterContext.HttpContext.User = new CustomPrincipal1(idn);
}
else
{          
     filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult((filterContext.Controller as Controller).
        Url.Action("Login", "User"));         
}
```

You can take in a property called ProviderName and based on that initialize CurrentProvider. That may also eliminate need for multiple custom attributes.

Note: Of course, CustomIdentity1(,2,3) is also based on which provider is used.
CustomIdentity1 is an implementation of IIdentity.
CustomPrincipal1 is an implementation of IPrincipal.